# using DPAPI from windows logon

Tags: windows, dpapi

I would like to read and unprotect on windows logon stage some data, protected using DPAPI `CryptProtectData()` with `CRYPTPROTECT_LOCAL_MACHINE` flag under some user.  Or it is possible only after logon under real operation system's user?

Answer (score 0):

You can use machine scope with DPAPI encryption at any stage (it's not very secure, by the way). Now, if you want to use user scope, then the user must be logged in with a loaded profile.